# Overlay android side-menu on "Unity as a plugin" rendering screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, kotlin, plugins, android-library

I am writing a requirement of Unity3D viewer for Android. I need to separate UI, Data and Unity3D View. for example, from model-tree, using ViewAPI, control the unity3d viewer.  Is it possible to implement as following image?

[Swipe from left overlays Model-tree menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaQ0l.png)